# Tag Entry Mode - AJAX option not working

Tags: ajax, tags

I have a Joomla 3.3.0 site that has been upgraded from 2.5.X to 3.2.x to the current version.  When we upgraded to 3.2, we began using Tags with our content, and all seemed well.

At some point, the tag entry system ceased using AJAX to enter tags, and switched to a scrolling list of existing tags.  I'd like to switch back to AJAX, to allow tag creation on the fly.  I've checked the Tags component, and set the Data Entry Options => Tag Entry Mode to AJAX, but the input field remains a scrolling list.

The template is a slightly modified version of Protostar, although I can confirm this is happening in Protostar as well.

Thank you for any help or advice you can give!

Comment: 1. Are there any Javascript errors in the browser console when you try to use it?
2. Which browsers have you tried e.g. IE, Chrome, Safari, Firefox?

Comment: Errors are:  
ReferenceError: Joomla is not defined create-a-page.html:4  

Use of getAttributeNode() is deprecated. Use getAttribute() instead. mootools-core.js:108  


SyntaxError: missing : after property id create-a-page.html:10  

Empty string passed to getElementById(). jquery.min.js:2'

Comment: If Javascript is saying Joomla is not defined then I'd say the core Javascript files are not being loaded. Check that you're page is loading `core.js` where `Joomla` is defined.

Comment: Hm, the template is a slight variation of Protostar, but the issue seems to persist even when I'm using the official Protostar template.  I do see <script src="/media/system/js/core.js" type="text/javascript"> being called under View Source for the page, near the bottom of the page (https://joomla.khronos.com)

Comment: Apparently, it's being called on the New Article page, but not on the index.

Comment: I added JHtml::_('jquery.ui', array('core', 'sortable')); to my index.php - no change, so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the system plugin ScriptsDown was installed, and I thought I'd removed it - that was the culprit.  Once it was disabled / removed, AJAX tags started working again.

Answer (score 1):

This usually happens because your browser cached an old version of the javascript / css files required for tags editing.

If you are not using any third-party cache, Shift-reload in the browser (or ctrl-reload depending on the browser) will fix this.

Else if you are using some fancy cache, clear the cache both from Joomla and from the cache manager. If you're using varnish, clear it there too.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not resolving the issue - even when I work from a fresh browser (I keep one to never remember history, and clear all cache on exit), the issue persists.  It seems like the option to use AJAX simply is not working - even when the option is selected, the interface is a selection list.

Browsers are Chrome, FireFox, and IE 11, all on Windows.

Comment: I just saw your comment to the question, what is "create-a-page.html" ? that's not a standard part of any template. And it's throwing an error at line 10, plus you didn't include the Joomla javascript libraries

Comment: That is the alias I use for creating a new article from scratch.  This is for an internal documentation site, so there's a "Start Here with a blank page" thing.